# ODBC call failed. The multipart identifier "(tablename)" could not be bound. (#4104)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

This query doesnt work when i run this query with tables from sql server as linked back end. But works just fine when tables are from linked ms access back end.

I think it has something to do with the join clause.

```
SELECT qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID, qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID, 
    CDbl(Nz(IIf(IsNull([tbl_Product_Quantity].[Stock_Recount_Date]),
    Sum([qry_Product_Transaction].[qty]),
    [tbl_Product_Quantity].[Stock_Recount_Quantity]+Sum(IIf([qry_Product_Transaction].[Date]>[tbl_product_quantity].[Stock_Recount_Date],[qry_Product_Transaction].[Qty],0))),0)) AS Current_Qty

FROM (qry_Product_Warehouse 
    LEFT JOIN qry_Product_Transaction ON (qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID = qry_Product_Transaction.Location) 
                                     AND (qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID = qry_Product_Transaction.Product)) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Product_Quantity ON (qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID = tbl_Product_Quantity.Product) 
                                  AND (qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID = tbl_Product_Quantity.Warehouse)

GROUP BY qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID, qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID, tbl_Product_Quantity.Stock_Recount_Quantity, tbl_Product_Quantity.Stock_Recount_Date;
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" does anything happen?

Comment: Message box pops up saying "ODBC call failed. The multipart identifier “(tablename)” could not be bound. (#4104)"

Comment: When SQL server is the back end can you open and see data in all of the tables and saved queries that you are using in your SQL statement?

Comment: Yes. Other queries work just fine